# jQuery hasClass then do something

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a div visible if a page has an element with a class of ".active-tag".

What I would like is, if the page has this class somewhere, then the div with the class of ".results-wrap" becomes visible (i.e. display: block).

I can't get it to work.

Here is where I'm at with it:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mCldo

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `toggle()` with a Boolean:

```
$('.results-wrap').toggle($('.active-tag').length > 0);
```

[JS Fiddle demo (showing)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UB3gF/1/), [JS Fiddle demo (hiding)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UB3gF/2/).

If there are more than zero elements with the `.active-tag` class the `.results-wrap` element will be shown, otherwise it will be, or will remain, hidden.

References:

- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help. If your problem is solved please do consider accepting an answer to your question (by clicking the check-mark besides the answer that most helped you, there's no obligation to choose this answer, go for whichever *most* helped).

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is to check whether the body tag has the class `active-tag`(still you need to remove the `.` from `hasClass()`). But from what I understood the class can be in any element so you need

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.active-tag').length) {
        $(".results-wrap").show();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fqH74/)

Comment: This works on my code pen, but not on my site, so I think the DOM is loading before the class is there or something.

Comment: @Jed whether the html is loaded dynamically

Comment: I think the class I'm trying to target might be. Im using Kirby CMS, and the tag pages have URLS with ":example" added to them, and the class is one one of those pages. Sorry, that probably makes no sense.

Comment: So perhaps I need to find another way to do this.

Comment: somehow you need to figure out when that content is loaded and then call this snippet after that

Comment: Thanks – I'll try. Although I thought document ready was supposed to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `if ($('body').hasClass('active-tag'))` (remove the period).